# Joomla SQL syntax error

Tags: php, select, mysqli, joomla

I use this code, my phpMyAdmin ver - 4.0.10.2

```
<?php 

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $pid = $forum['Review']['listing_id'];

    $ipaddress = $forum['User']['ipaddress'];

    $query = "SELECT count(ipaddress) AS addresses_found FROM threads WHERE ipaddress = {$ipaddress} AND pid = {$pid}";

    $count_ip = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();

    if($count_ip >= 2){
    echo '<p> Your ip repeated </ p>';
    }

    ?>
```

and see this error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND pid = 315' at line 1 SQL=SELECT count(ipaddress) AS addresses_found FROM threads WHERE ipaddress = 127.0.0.0 AND pid = 315

What is that ?

Answer (score 6):

> *"what it that ?"*

It means that `$ipaddress` contains characters that MySQL is complaining about, being a string, and unlike the integer for `{$pid}` which can remain the same (if that column is also an int).

`WHERE ipaddress = {$ipaddress}`

The `$ipaddress` variable needs to be wrapped in quotes:

`WHERE ipaddress = '$ipaddress'`

On an added note; your code is prone to an SQL injection. It's best to use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Should there be any user input or interaction.

Comment: You beat me to it. Indeed, ip addresses contain dots. Again, the betting system is needed here :)

Comment: thx guys ! worked with '$pid' !
please, explain me about SQL injection. how can i protect this code ?

Comment: You're welcome @Brigadier see the link that's in my answer. It explains it and contains external links you can consult.

Comment: You're welcome @Brigadier I think you know what to do in order to properly close the question now ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $forum['List']['id']);
$ipaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $forum['User']['ipaddress']);   //  this code is better ?